# How to group or cluster polar coordinate system data in python

Tags: python, cluster-analysis

I have an RPLidar and my task is to detect an obstacle. From the sensor, I am getting a set of truples which contains the quality of signal, angle and distance in mm.

Here are the example:

```
[(15, 1.375, 2569.0), (15, 3.0, 2491.5), (15, 4.578125, 2528.75), (15, 6.203125, 2419.75), (15, 7.796875, 2299.75), (15, 9.40625, 2200.5), (15, 11.078125, 2104.25), (15, 12.703125, 2047.25), (15, 14.3125, 2091.75), (15, 15.84375, 2132.25), (15, 17.46875, 2183.75), (15, 19.015625, 2232.5), (15, 20.609375, 2288.75), (15, 22.15625, 2341.0), (15, 23.765625, 2411.0), (15, 25.34375, 2481.0), (15, 26.875, 2554.25), (15, 28.453125, 2641.0), (15, 30.046875, 2731.5), (15, 31.609375, 2824.0), (15, 33.1875, 2854.75), (11, 39.8125, 2178.0), (15, 41.390625, 2278.0), (15, 42.984375, 2199.5), (13, 44.546875, 2269.0), (15, 46.171875, 2265.5), (15, 47.71875, 2300.75), (15, 49.3125, 2454.25), (15, 50.890625, 2442.0), (15, 52.484375, 2415.0), (15, 54.109375, 2404.0), (15, 55.703125, 2390.0), (15, 57.28125, 2371.0), (15, 58.796875, 2357.5), (15, 60.421875, 2348.5), (15, 61.984375, 2344.0), (15, 63.5625, 2340.5), (15, 65.171875, 2332.75), (15, 66.75, 2328.25), (15, 68.34375, 2330.75), (15, 69.984375, 2324.5), (15, 71.515625, 2328.25), (15, 73.125, 2332.75), (15, 74.71875, 2335.75), (15, 76.28125, 2341.5)]
```

I have plot those data in a matplotlib and that is how they look like:

[image: ![enter image description here]

As you can see i am getting the surroundings information as point and each point has quality,angle,distance from the center. Now i want to group them and need to find the length of the each group. how can i achive this? is there any library available in python by which i can do the clustering like as bellow?[image]

Comment: Great question. I will be following this question closely to learn the answer.

Comment: What do you mean by the length of each group?

Comment: Questions regarding the type of Algorithm to use can also be asked on CrossValidated SE

Comment: From a single cluster if you subtract the last point to the first point then you would get the length of that particular cluster @Nightmerker

Comment: Copied from a link-only answer: http://benalexkeen.com/k-means-clustering-in-python/ & https://github.com/SparkingTime/K-MeansViaSpark

Comment: i've some code working for this lidar and DBscan if you're interested

Answer (score 3):

Obvious solution #1:

Project your data from polar coordinates to carthesian coordinates. Then you can use any coordinate-based algorithm such as k-means, and anything that works with Euclidean distance (e.g., HAC, DBSCAN)

Obvious solution #2:

Compute the pairwise distances in polar coordinates. That will likely be more complicated and thus slower for large data than above approach, but a bit more obvious. When you have the distance matrix, use any distance-based algorithm such as HAC, DBSCAN, affinity propagation, spectral clustering.

Based on your plots, I'd project and use DBSCAN.

Comment: thank you very much for your such informative answer. I just have one question. can you please tell me , by using the DBSCAN algorithm, is it possible to work with polar coordinates or I must convert it to cartesian before implementing the algorithm? @anony-mousse

Comment: DBSCAN can work on any data, as long as you know how to compute the distances.

Comment: What is the best library for DBSCAN? I am totally new in this field. I will be glad if you could provide some source where i can learn that algorithm

Comment: ELKI is easiest to enhance with custom distances. The sklearn version becomes very slow with custom distances, and the R version only allows using a precomputed distance matrix I believe. Projecting the data, as recommended, will work in each of them *and* will likely be faster and easier to understand.